# Download PDF from a URL that generates it on android studio

Tags: android, pdf

I am trying to download then open a pdf file on a url on android but the url does not contain any  .pdf extension.

The pdf downloads once the url is loaded on a browser, any solution on how to download the pdf without opening the browser then viewing it on a pdf reader or any way to download the pdf using that url

I'm a currently new on stack overflow, i hope any one can help me

Answer (score 0):

You could use .net framework and load the URL .pdf to your memory and store it somewhere.

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
    var data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    // save to your local system, or open reader.
}
```

Comment: Hi, i'm currently new to this function. Can you post an example? I'll really appreciate it!